# Show and hide UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I use this code so that when I click on **button 1**, **button 2** is hidden

```
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
    button2.isHidden = false
}
```

How can I make it so that when you press **button 1** again, **button 2** is displayed.

Comment: `@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
    button2.isHidden = ! button2.isHidden
}` Use this

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this tricks:

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    button2.isHidden = !button2.isHidden
}
```